# Looping through buttons in tkinter

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, python-3.6

I have written the following code to create 4 buttons and after clicking at a button the background color of this button is changing and when I click at another one the color of this one is now changing and the color of the old one is changing back to default color. It works quite well but the coding is not efficient. I'm thinking of a loop which iterates through all my buttons to set all buttons which are not active to the default color. How can I accomplish this?

```
from tkinter import *


def update_Button(number):
  if number == 1:
    Button_1["background"] = Button_1["activebackground"] = "lightblue"
    Button_2.configure(background="SystemButtonFace")
    Button_3.configure(background="SystemButtonFace")
    Button_4.configure(background="SystemButtonFace")
  elif number == 2:
    Button_2["background"] = Button_2["activebackground"] = "lightblue"
    Button_1.configure(background="SystemButtonFace")
    Button_3.configure(background="SystemButtonFace")
  elif number == 3:
    Button_3["background"] = Button_3["activebackground"] = "lightblue"
    Button_2.configure(background="SystemButtonFace")
    Button_1.configure(background="SystemButtonFace")
    Button_4.configure(background="SystemButtonFace")
  elif number == 4:
    Button_4["background"] = Button_4["activebackground"] = "lightblue"
    Button_2.configure(background="SystemButtonFace")
    Button_3.configure(background="SystemButtonFace")
    Button_1.configure(background="SystemButtonFace")

  pass


root = Tk()

Button_font = ("Calibri", 20, "bold")
Button_Size = [70, 70]  # width, height
pady = 5
padx = 5

Button_1 = Button(root, text="1", font=Button_font, command=lambda:  update_Button(1))
Button_1.grid(sticky="wens", pady=pady, padx=padx)

Button_2 = Button(root, text="2", font=Button_font, command=lambda: update_Button(2))
Button_2.grid(sticky="wens", pady=pady, padx=padx)

Button_3 = Button(root, text="3", font=Button_font, command=lambda: update_Button(3))
Button_3.grid(sticky="wens", pady=pady, padx=padx)

Button_4 = Button(root, text="4", font=Button_font, command=lambda: update_Button(4))
Button_4.grid(sticky="wens", pady=pady, padx=padx)

root.mainloop()
```

like suggest from @Mitiku the solution using a list is:

```
def update_Button(number):
  number = number-1
  buttons = [Button_1, Button_2, Button_3, Button_4]
  buttons[number]["background"] = buttons[number]["activebackground"] = "lightblue"
  for button in buttons:
    if button == buttons[number]:
        pass
    else:
        button.configure(background="SystemButtonFace")
  pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below achieves what you need:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.number = 4 #change me to get more buttons
        self.buttons = []
        for i in range(self.number):
            self.buttons.append(Button(self.root, text="Change!", bg="white", command=lambda c=i: self.command(c)))
            self.buttons[i].pack()
    def command(self, var):
        for i in range(self.number):
            self.buttons[i].configure({"bg": "white", "activebackground": "white"})
        self.buttons[var].configure({"bg": "lightblue", "activebackground": "lightblue"})

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The main interesting mechanic we use here is `lambda`.

We declare `command=lambda c=i: self.command(c)` which let's us call the `command` callback with the value of `i` at the time of declaration. This means when we call the command we pass through the integer value of the `Button` widget's position in the `list`.

---

On a side note, this can be accomplished much easier with `Radiobutton`s. See below:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.v = IntVar()
        self.number = 4 #change me to get more buttons
        self.buttons = []
        for i in range(self.number):
            self.buttons.append(Radiobutton(self.root, text="Change!", bg="white", activebackground="lightblue", selectcolor="lightblue", variable=self.v, indicatoron=0, value=i))
            self.buttons[i].pack()

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This works perfectly and is even more than i had in mind. No I want to color just one button at a time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "No I want to color just one button at a time" what do you mean? This does colour just one at a time.

Comment: I was refering to comment which seems to be deleted.

Comment: My fault, I misread your code and assumed you were doing something that you actually weren't. Blame it on a lack of caffeine today!

Comment: @Max2603 I've added an alternate solution you might like too.

Comment: That is awesome, I didn`t know that radibuttons can do this otherwise I would have choosen them in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

you can use list.

```
    def update_Button(number):
        buttons = [Button_1,Button_2,Button_3,Button_4]
        for button in buttons:
            button.configure(background="SystemButtonFace")
        buttons[number-1]["activebackground"] = "lightblue"
```

Comment: This is not working for me but with a litte modification it is, see above. Thanks